# What is the purpose of the controlling terminal?

Tags: command-line

Say that I have opened some program from the terminal, and I have redirected its `stdin` and `stdout` and `stderr` to three files.

Even though this program no longer send its output to the terminal and no longer receive its input from the terminal, the program still has a "link" to the terminal. The terminal that the program has this "link" with is called the **controlling terminal**, the following image illustrates this:

[image]

My question is: what is the purpose of the controlling terminal, my guess is that the controlling terminal can be used to send signals to the program (for example: `Ctrl+C`).

Are there other purposes for the controlling terminal?

Comment: It doesn't have a link to the terminal now. Why do you think that?

Comment: @Olorin The program still has a link to the terminal because if you press for example `Ctrl+C` on the terminal, the program will receive a `SIGINT` signal.

Comment: @Olorin And if you don't `disown` the program's process or start it with `nohup` in the first place, it will be `SIGHUP`ed when you close the terminal – that's the “link” OP talks about IMO.

Comment: @dessert and John in both these cases the link is the other way around: there's a link from the terminal to the process, but not from the process to the terminal. Once those fds are closed, it will have to do some trickery using parent-process info to get back a connection to the controlling tty

Comment: @Olorin: That is the case for all child processes that aren't equipped with a specific communication channel to their parent process by the latter (disregarding `kill(ppid(), ...)` which all processes whose parent is still alive can do). In any case, in the situation in question there's still `/dev/tty` that refers to the character device associated with the parent terminal.